# Possible Test cases for "We should allow user to have easy way to contact support via web site"

Tags: manual-testing, testcase, requirements-validation

When writing test cases  for "Contact us" link, what should I write for this requirement 
"We should allow user to have easy way to contact support via web site"

Comment: Can they define what they mean by "easy"?

Comment: This is their answer--what they mean by easy---"Currently user can only contact us via FB and Twitter, which results in long time to response from our side. Adding link to site will make easy and fast way of sending us message and we will have in one place all customer messages"

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, below are the possible test cases for checking the contact us link.

### Assumption

1. Consider Contact us is a link, on clicking the link will open a popup with contact us form or it will redirects to the page with contact us form
2. If it is a popup , then all the fields in the popup should be validated. For example email id field.
3. Popup means it should have a close icon . On clicking the close icon the popup needs to be closed.
4. If the popup has submit button , on clicking the submit button support query should be submitted with a success message.
5. Verify the admin section to check the submitted query is stored or not. In some systems, they have integrated with a  ticketing system to track the support questions.
6. On clicking the cancel button in popup should close the popup without saving any pre-entered data.
7. Clicking the contact us link consecutively(assume two question need to be asked individually) should not populate the popup with pre-entered data.
8. If the contact us form on a page, all the fields need to be validated before submitting the support request.
9. Submit and cancel button needs to be validated.

Answer (score 1):

If I was handed a site that had a "contact us" link and a requirement of "we should allow users to to have an easy way  to contact support via web site" I would start with these questions:

- How do you define an "easy" way to contact support?
- What is this link supposed to do? I can think of several options right away:

  - Open a popup form for the user to fill out
  - Act as a mailto: link and open the user's default email client with the support team email address as the to address
  - Start a live chat session with a support team member
  - Open a web page listing all the ways one can contact the support team
  - Open a web page with a list of all the knowledge base/help topics for the site and an option to contact the support team if the information on the page isn't enough.
  - If the browser has a Skype or other IP phone plugin, call the support number
- What form of contact is required? One or more methods?
- Is the link supposed to appear on every page of the app? Specific pages? If specific, which pages?

That would probably get the requirement updated very quickly to something I would call Definition of Ready - that is, all the information needed to build and test the feature is in the requirement.

From there I'd look at these broad test scenarios (because there currently isn't enough information for test:

- Does the link appear where it's supposed to be?
- Does clicking the link perform the expected function?
- Does the expected function handle expected and unexpected input gracefully?
- Does the contact reach the expected recipient(s)?

Comment: This is their answer--what they mean by easy---"Currently user can only contact us via FB and Twitter, which results in long time to response from our side. Adding link to site will make easy and fast way of sending us message and we will have in one place all customer messages" –

Answer (score 0):

Every software testing company follow test case creation process to test the quality of any website support link. Below are the few test cases for checking the contact us link:

1. Verify that 'Contact Us' link is clickable and user is able to access it.
2. Verify that all the fields of contact us link are editable and user is able to enter valid text in it.
3. Verify that user is able to send the query to support team through contact us link.
4. Verify that confirmation message is displayed after submitting the query.
5. Verify that contact us pop up is not accepting invalid email addresses of the user.
6. Verify that on submitting multiple queries it should not pre-populate the previously entered data.
7. Verify that on clicking the cancel button in popup it closes the popup without saving any pre-populated data.